# Access the database from outside using a SSH tunnel Fortrabbit

Tags: ssh, fortrabbit

I copy command from form Fortrabbit to access my database using a SSH tunnel:

```
#Access the database from outside using a SSH tunnel
ssh -N -L 13306:myapp.mysql.eu1.frbit.com:3306 u-my-app@ssh2.eu1.frbit.com
```

[image]

I entered my passphrase. But when I hit enter nothing happens.
Could anyone help?

Comment: What were you expecting to happen when you hit enter?

Comment: Access the database @Kenster

Answer (score 1):

You have set up a port forwarding from your localhost:3306 to remoteport:3306.
What this means is the mysql database runinng on remote machine is now accessible at your localhost port 3306.

You can connect it using

**Shell**

```
mysql -u <username> -p<password> --host=127.0.0.1 --port=3306
```

**JDBC**

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/<db_name>";
Class.forName ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance ();
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection (url, "username", "password");
```

This will only work as long as the SSh session opened previosly is alive.

Answer (score 1):

That nothing *seems* to happen is a good sign:

The connection seems established, and you can, *in a separate terminal window*, use that existing connection for your mysql work.

See also the fortrabbit tutorial on mysql connection:

https://help.fortrabbit.com/mysql